# What update is needed in jmeter.properties and jmeter-server files to create a JMeter Remote Load Test

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, rmi

I am using jmeter 5.4.1, and facing issue while setting up the whole environment for that.
I have firewall in between master and slave machines.
I can request for some ports to open but before that I want to know how to configure them?
What update is needed in jmeter.properties and jmeter-server files to create a JMeter Remote Load Test.

Answer (score 0):

[In *jmeter.properties* nothing, don't touch this file, perform all the configuration either in *user.properties*](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter) or via [-J command-line arguments](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override).

Coming back to your question, I believe the [official documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) is quite comprehensive, however just in case you cannot or unwilling to read:

1. In the master:

   ```
   remote_hosts=ip,addresses,or,dns,hostnames,of,slaves,separated,by,comma
   client.rmi.localport=xxxx
   ```
2. In the slave(s):

   ```
   client.rmi.localport=xxxx
   server.rmi.localport=yyyy
   ```

If you don't want secure communication between master and slaves - add the next line to both as well:

```
server.rmi.ssl.disable=true
```

So in the firewall you need to open these `xxxx` and `yyyy` ports

More information:

- [Apache JMeter Distributed Testing Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html)
- [Remote hosts and RMI configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote)
- [JMeter Distributed Testing with Docker](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-distributed-testing-with-docker)